# Redux-React populate initialState with api call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

populate my initialState with json api call from a component or from here

```
const initialState = {
      myvalues: [] ---->here i want to populate this array
    };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Update":
      console.log(newState);
    // newState.myvalues = action.key.title.value;
    default:
      return newState;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate your `initialState` with data from an API, you can create e.g. an `FETCH_INIT_DATA_ACTION`, which get's dispatched right after you initialised your store.

```js
// ...
const store = createStore(/* ... */)

store.dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT_DATA_ACTION' })

// ...
```

whereas `FETCH_INIT_DATA_ACTION` triggers a redux-thunk, saga, effect or whatever you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Update":
      return { ...state, myvalues: action.payload }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And when you dispatch it you should put your API data in `payload`.

Comment: Not sure why you need const newState ? Just return the state if default ?

Comment: @dorriz yep sure. I just copied his code to change the `Update` case and I didn't even see that newState. Thanks :)